# Solving SDE with sign function in drift term?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following SDE with $X_0 = 1$,
$$
dX_t = X_t\operatorname{sign}(X_t) \, dt + X_t \, dW_t,
$$
where $\operatorname{sign}(x) = \mathbb{1}\{x \ge 0\}$. How am I supposed to solve this SDE?

Comment: show it never hits zero, then the  sign($X_t$) is moot.

Comment: @mike I did think about this, but I do not know how to show it never hits zero.

Comment: unitl it hits 0 it satisfies the equation of geometric brownian motion,  and since a geometric brownian motion does not hit 0, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as mentioned in the comments one can return to a geometric BM. We start with the Lamperti transformation 2.1.5/2.1.6 from ["The Lamperti Transform"](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A948769c8-49e5-4175-9990-76b3235f7a25) by de Boer. First using Ito to compute for general map $\psi$.

[image]

then for this specific $\psi$ below, they turn the volatility coefficient to be one.

[image]

So here we have $Z_{t}=\psi(X_{t})=\log X_{t}$ and so it satisfies the SDE for geometric BM

$$dZ_{t}=(0+\frac{e^{Z_{t}}1\{e^{Z_{t}}\geq 0\}}{e^{Z_{t}}}-\frac{1}{2})+dW_{t}=\frac{1}{2}dt+dW_{t}.$$